# Easy looking at Android source code without downloading full code

Tags: android

I want to modify say MediaRecorder class for example. And I want to show at full source code of it.

Where can I get source code of standard classes?

Comment: Stackoverflow providing the solution of the question . Not the Source code .

Comment: I thinks he need view source code of classes in standard library of Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://source.android.com/

> Here [at the link above] you can find the information and source code you need to build an Android-compatible device.
>
> Android is an open-source software stack for mobile devices, and a corresponding open-source project led by Google. We created Android in response to our own experiences launching mobile apps. We wanted to make sure that there was no central point of failure, so that no industry player can restrict or control the innovations of any other. That's why we created Android, and made its source code open.

Answer (score 1):

[Easy looking at code without downloading full Android source code](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/)